# Getting extra lines in CSV when converting from a HTML table

Tags: php, html, dom, csv

i am getting the CSV output as in this photo, which inserts extra blank lines in between the data. Can it be fixed? I tried trim(). But it didn't work.

[image: Urgent ?]

Comment: paste your csv content please

Comment: This is the CSV content in photo http://i.imgur.com/x2mWb.png
Rest content is 

    "Header 1","Header 2","Header 3"
    
    
    "row 1, cell 1","row 1, cell 2","row 1, cell 3"
    
    "row 2, cell 1","row 2, cell 2","row 2, cell 3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
if (!empty($td))
```

before each fputcsv() call.

THs only exist in the first iteration and TDs don't exist in the first iteration so you're probably adding empty data on every iteration.